# Java BufferedOutputStream vs OutputStream

Tags: java, outputstream

What are the differences between BufferedOutputStream and OutputStream.

What i've read is that bos is faster and better for large file than os but i don't really understand why. Hope to get some clarification and insight on these 2 topics.

Answer (score 2):

AS IO operations are costlier, BufferedOutputStream first writes them in buffer and write the chunk on underlying OutputStream. BufferedOutputStream  uses decorator patterns where it attaches the additional responisibilty at run time to OutputStream.

Same is true for BufferedInputStream which reads the bytes in chunk and place them in buffer. When actual read operation occurs , it reads from that buffer instead of underlying InputStream like disk which is costlier

Comment: Can anyone tell whats wrong with this answer ? Down vote without any reason is really discouraging ..